# window.open() is not working inside asynchronus function in IOS only

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I developed a `ReactJS` app that's embedded inside a `webview` for android and ios.

I have a button that redirect to a new website. If this button is clicked for the first time, an api call will be triggered and then do the redirection using `window.open`, and if it is clicked for the second time, the api call will not be triggered and the redirection is applied directly.

Here is the code

```
    let windowReference = window.open("", "_blank");
  //first time
  if (reward == null) {
       let resp = await activate();
       if (resp.ok) {
            if (windowReference == null || windowReference.closed) {
                window.open(myUrl, "_blank");
            } else {
                windowReference.location = myUrl; 
            }
       }
  } else {
       //second time
      if (windowReference == null || windowReference.closed) {
                window.open(myUrl, "_blank");
            } else {
                windowReference.location = myUrl; 
            }
  }
```

This code works fine on `android webview` and `browser`, but in `ios webview` , the first time it will do nothing but the second click navigate to myUrl just fine.

Things I tried are

1. place the logic inside async response inside `setTimeout`
2. change `_blank` with `_self`

Still nothing changes

Is there something I am missing.

Please if you can help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is By default IOS Safari has a strict popup blocker compared to other browsers, which might prevent it from opening the new window.

To fix this issue, you can open the window in response to the user's gesture. You could also try to open the new window in a separate function that is called asynchronously, but not inside an async function.

Example :

```
function handleOpenNewWindow() {
let windowReference = window.open("", "_blank");
if (windowReference == null || windowReference.closed) {
  window.open(myUrl, "_blank");
} else {
windowReference.location = myUrl;
 }
}
 //---  call handleOpenNewWindow() asynchronously here ---
 let resp = await activate();
 if (resp.ok) {
 setTimeout(handleOpenNewWindow, 0);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you,  will try this and get back to you

Comment: That didn't work, still the same problem, the navigation seems to work then disappear

Comment: didn't work for me either :(